# How do I keep the state in the redux form after I unmounted the form

Tags: redux, redux-form

I have a component which renders multiple forms based on schema, and the problem is that I will change the schema, I will rerender the forms, and the state cannot keep.

The code looks like the following:

```
    {schemas.map(schema => (
      <div key={schema.$id}>
        <h3 id={schema.$id}>
          {schema.title}
        </h3>
        // a library using the redux form to keep the state.
        <Liform
          schema={schema}
          onSubmit={value => console.log(`Submit ${JSON.stringify(value)}`)}
          {...rest}
        />
      </div>
    ))}
```

When I change the schemas, all of these forms will be rerendered, so that I cannot keep the state of the form which have the same formName, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on the redux-form api you can pass a prop
`destroyOnUnmount={false}` to you form component. or in you reduxForm() initialization

i have used it myself and it keeps the form state on re-render

https://redux-form.com/7.2.3/docs/api/reduxform.md/#-code-destroyonunmount-boolean-code-optional-